# Jersey 1.17 rate limit

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jetty

I want to limit the download rate in my REST service, this is my code:

```
@GET
@Path("/laboDownloadWithLimit")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response getFile()
{
    final File file = new File("SampleVideo_1280x720_50mb.mp4");

    final StreamingOutput streamingOutput = new StreamingOutput()
    {

        @Override
        public void write(
            final OutputStream outputStream)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException
        {
            final InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            int len;
            while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
            {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
        }

    };
    return Response.ok(streamingOutput)
        .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE)
       .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"" ).build();
}
```

But I think that exists better way to solve this problem, what should I use? I'm using Jetty 7.4.5

Comment: You could look on how Jetty implements it in their servlet: DataRateLimitedServlet. Reading their code, i think your implementation is not that far off. They just seem to use a scheduler for the write operations, however you have that wrapped in your output, so that should really be fine

Answer (score 1):

Where you're doing `thread.sleep(10)` you might look at using something a little more measured, like a generalized [`RateLimiter`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `java SDK` has a built in method to throttle input streams. I would also question *why* you would want to slow it down. I have to assume that you have performance or denial of service concerns.

These concerns are better addressed by using a [jetty DoS Filter](http://www.codeoriented.com/jetty-slow-http-denial-of-service-attack/). I am not sure that forcing thread context switches every 10 milliseconds is actually helping. In actual fact you may be introducing inefficiencies by context switching more often than necessary. You should be able to rely on the infrastructure you are using.

Sorry I can't offer an actual asynchronous or callback solution :-)